# LabVIEW: Extract data after a certain line

Tags: labview

Any advice or help would be much appreciated.

**Question**: How to extract data after a certain line from a comma deliminated strings which are read from a serial port ?

*More Info:* A have a card that is gathering data values and is read into the computer via a serial port. Example string of data acquired as below:

```
;Data = 1 bps Tool = Sensor
;Label, Time, Voltage, Pressure, Temperature, Current
A, 01:33, 5.1, 18.1, 31.2, -, 
B, 01:34, 5.5, 19.2, 30.5, -, 
;Data = 1 bps Tool = Sensor
;Label, Time, Voltage, Pressure, Temperature, Current 
A, 01:35, 5.3, 18.3, 30.1, -, 
B, 01:36, 5.1, 19.0, 30.5, -, 
;Data = 1 bps Tool = Sensor
;Label, Time, Voltage, Pressure, Temperature, Current 
A, 01:37, 5.1, 18.1, 30.8, -, 
B, 01:38, 5.3, 19.2, 30.1, -,
```

These data value will be kept updating line by line. I would like to start extracting the data only on the 3rd block of incoming data. I would not want the first 2 blocks of incoming data.

*Further Info:* Currently, my idea of doing that is to scan the ";Data" and put it into a counter. If there are 2 ";Data" scan, then from the counter it woud output a True value to a case structure to start extracting the data. Please see my attached photo.

However, I am not able to create such a counter using an array as I cannot use a while loop and shift register. Do you have any idea how to start extracting data from 3rd block onwards ? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Why can't you use while loop and shift register ?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I understand the question properly.  Here is my solution:

[image]

Code can be found here: http://raptorview.net/StackOverflow/SO19920265.vi